# Are there any other animals in the “real world”?

Tags: the-matrix

In *The Matrix*, Agent Smith has this quote during his monologue with Morpheus.

> **Smith:** I realized that you're not actually mammals. Every mammal on this planet instinctively develops a natural equilibrium with their surrounding environment, but you humans do not.

Leaving aside the fact that this is not true, has Morpheus ever seen an animal (of any kind) outside of the Matrix, or are the Humans that are kept alive by the machines  the only life that survived?

It’s unlikely they have animals for food, given Dozer’s quote

> **Dozer:** It's a single-celled protein combined with synthetic aminos, vitamins, and minerals. Everything the body needs.

alongside the fact that Cypher apparently sold out the crew for a steak. But that just tells us that there aren’t cows or chickens.

Is there any evidence of non-human (multicellular) life outside the Matrix?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can there be animals on the surface in Zion's world?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/166232/how-can-there-be-animals-on-the-surface-in-zions-world) as well as [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/71564/98028), both of which and their answers already provide evidence of multicellular wildlife outside the Matrix.

Comment: Yes, the first one in particular presupposes the answer to my question is yes. In my search I only found the questions about animals _inside_ The Matrix though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Matrix comic The Miller’s Tale, protagonist Geoffrey and team are on a mission up on the surface to one of the scorched human megacities. (No spoilers as to why unless you want that detail)

There they encounter “animals, such as frogs and ducks” still living around it.

Source: The Matrix Comics Series 3

Comment: For the record, I've systematically identified every single animal depicted in every single matrix film, animated feature and comic [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71564/why-are-there-no-animals-in-the-matrix)

Comment: @Valorum that’s a better answer than the one this is marked a duplicate of, because of the monkey in Matriculated.

Comment: @BenMurphy - I'd make it a dupe of both if I had the tag badge needed to do it.